# Customized Table Names in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Table 1`. I'm trying to create an after-insert trigger for a `Table 1`; whereby, whenever a user enters a record, the trigger will create a new table **named after** the record that triggered its creation.

Please help, I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What does "*NAMED AFTER the record*" mean?

Comment: And this sounds like a _really_ bad idea in the first place.  What overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Triggers should be very small, lean, fast - do **NOT** do extensive computation or create new database objects inside a trigger - that's a horribly bad idea.

Comment: so you plan on having a SQL server instance with a table for every row in another table? so if there are 1000 rows, there will be 1000 other tables? major code smell here.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds super non-relational-database-design-ish. I would heavily advise against this in almost every case. And I say "almost" only to allow for artistic freedom of development, I can't think of a single case where this would be appropriate.

That said, if you do in fact want this, you can use dynamic SQL to create a table.

You can build the SQL in your trigger, but basically you want something like:

```
EXEC 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + ' (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))';
```

Of course, the columns are up to you, but that should get you started.

---

But while we're at it, what you *should* (probably) be doing is using a single table with a one-to-many relationship to the table on which your trigger is currently assigned.

For instance, if you have a table `Users` with a column for `email` and you're looking to create a table for each user's favorites on your website, you should instead consider adding an identity column for user `ID`s, then reference that in a single `UserFavorites` table that has `UserId` and `PostId` columns, and the appropriate foreign keys implemented.